# ACCESS SQL query not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

i have sql query it works with select * but when i put column names it does not show data.

```
$sql2="SELECT PSO_NAME, PSO_SIGNATURE, PSO_DATE FROM SIGNATURES_DASO WHERE DASO_NO ='".$daso_no."'";
echo $sql2; //it shows the query which i tested in access runs fine.
$rs_pso_sign=odbc_exec($conn,$sql2);
if (!$rs_pso_sign) {
  exit("Error in SIGNATURE TABLE INFO SQL");
}

if(odbc_fetch_row($rs_pso_sign)){

                $psoName = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "PSO_NAME");
                $psoSign = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "PSO_SIGNATURE");
                $psoDate = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "PSO_DATE");
                echo $psoName;
         }
else
 {
 echo "$psoName does not exist";
}
```

it works when i do

```
 $sql2="SELECT * FROM SIGNATURES_DASO WHERE DASO_NO ='".$daso_no."'";
```

i checked from database column names are the same no typo mistake as well.

any suggestions?

Comment: In the 1st case the script returns the error msg or what ?

Comment: it returns  blank, nothing. no error message. does not bring back any row from the database table

Comment: The columns are they in the same order in your database or what?

Comment: The column order should not matter. I suspect that one of the column names is wrong. Try just one column name - one that you are certain is right.

Comment: If not you try to remove spaces before their names.

Comment: @mazux they are in the same order, the spelling are correct as well. removed spaces, did not work.